Is there covariance between the sample mean and beta regression coefficients?
In linear regression, is there a covariance between the sample mean and the beta regression estimates?
E.g. Here is the model:
$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i $$
In this set up, $\bar{y}$ is the sample mean of the dependent variable and $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean of the independent variable.
I want to find out:
$$ Cov(\bar{y}, \hat{\beta_1})$$
I first wrote the OLS estimate:
$$ \hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} $$
I then wrote $\bar{y}$ in terms of $y_i$:
$$ \bar{y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i $$
Putting everything together:
$$ Cov(\bar{y}, \hat{\beta_1}) = E[(\bar{y} - E[\bar{y}])(\hat{\beta_1} - E[\hat{\beta_1}])] $$
Then subbing in the formulas:
$$ Cov(\bar{y}, \hat{\beta_1}) = E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i - E[\bar{y}]\right)\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} - E[\hat{\beta_1}]\right)\right] $$
But I am not sure how to continue from here.
I think the covariance does exist (i.e. non-zero) because $\bar{y}$ has uncertainty from the sample and $\hat{\beta_1}$ has uncertainty from the sample ... but I am not sure if regression theory says that the covariance between these is fundamentally 0, or approximately 0 in expectation under large samples, or actually non-zero.
How should I proceed here?

A simulation (as requested by Henry):
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

n_sims <- 10000

simulate_and_fit <- function(n = 100) {
    x <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    y <- 2 + 3 * x + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    model <- lm(y ~ x)
    return(c(x_bar = mean(x), beta1_hat = coef(model)[2]))
}

results <- replicate(n_sims, simulate_and_fit())
results_df <- data.frame(x_bar = results[1,], beta1_hat = results[2,])

correlation <- cor(results_df$x_bar, results_df$beta1_hat)

ggplot(results_df, aes(x = x_bar, y = beta1_hat)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "red") +
    labs(title = "Relationship between x-bar and beta1-hat",
         x = "x-bar",
         y = "beta1-hat") +
    annotate("text", x = min(results_df$x_bar), y = max(results_df$beta1_hat), 
             label = paste("Correlation:", round(correlation, 4)), 
             hjust = 0, vjust = 1) +
    theme_minimal()


Looks like there is no correlation - but how can we show this mathematically?

In "I think the covariance does exist (i.e. non-zero)", do you think it should be positive or negative? Perhaps simulation (reusing the same $x_i, \beta_0, \beta_1, \sigma^2_\epsilon$ each time) might suggest an answer to you, allowing for simulation noise.

@ Henry: Good idea ... I was thinking about this myself

@Henry : please see the update

From
$$\bar y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar x + \bar\epsilon = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar x + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i$$
and
$$\hat\beta_1 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2_x} \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j-\bar x)\epsilon_j$$
and the assumptions that the $\epsilon_i$ are iid with finite variance $\sigma^2,$  invoke the bilinearity of covariance and the fact that the residuals $x_j-\bar x$ sum to zero to compute
$$\operatorname{Cov}(\bar y, \hat\beta_1) = \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-\bar x)\operatorname{Cov}(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j) = \frac{1}{n\sigma_x^2}\sum_{j=1}^n (x_j- \bar x) \sigma^2 = 0.$$
